# Download a website from Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, dotnetnuke

I have deployed the website on my Azure account using DNN platform. Right now I need to run this website locally on my PC. I have installed a "Open From Azure Websites" extension for the Visual Studio: 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/60d414b1-4ead-4fde-9359-588aa126cd6c

I have downloaded from an Azure my publish settings file and opened it in the Visual Studio: File -> Open From Azure Websites.

The process of downloading files is interrupted with the following error:

"An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. An error was encountered when processing operation 'Read File' on 'write.lock'"

Can somebody help with it?

Comment: are you looking to redeploy this site or just test against it locally?

Comment: I need to customize this website in Visual Studio and publish  it.

Comment: probably not the best way to go about it.  what exactly do you need to customize, a skin / theme, a module, the build in dnn core functions.  The amount of settings you have to change for the environment makes publishing a local site to a remote azure web app a difficult process.  DNN is modular and works by creating extensions to extend the functionality of the site.  Each theme/skin or module is an extension.  Its best to modify and then reinstall/upload these extensions into the dnn instance.

Comment: most developers have a local install that they develop these extensions in and then install them in their live sites.  I recommend learning how to create your own extension visual studio project and learn how to modify that way.  If you need to just adjust some css then you can get away with some ftp transfers.  but otherwise google christoc templates for dnn and learn from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems IIS has a lock on you 'write.lock' file, you can exclude the file when you are downloading the site.

Comment: so I cannot use "Open in Azure website" extension in this way. Right?

Answer (score 0):

this is more complicated than just downloading and running.  Are you looking to redeploy this site to azure or just work with it locally for testing.  If just local testing, I use ftp and just download the site files, then you have to change the connection string to a local db that is a copy of your azure db and then you have to adjust your hosts file to point to the site and the associated portal alias(s) in dotnetnuke.

Have a look at link below for more detailed steps

http://www.ifinity.com.au/2012/09/05/Creating_a_test_copy_of_your_DotNetNuke_website

Comment: That page says _The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred._